# Como recuperar los datos autocompletados o en cache de mi firefox?

Tags: firefox

tengo cierta informacion en mi firefox que quiero recuperar, son una serie de datos auto-completados(emails,usuarios,....) que estan guardados en el cache pero no se si pueda recuperarlos para poderlos guardarlos en una lista txt o extrar mi informacion para poder recuperarlo.

¿Es posible recuperar datos que estan guardados en el cache?

¿O al menos extraerlos para tenerlos de manera ordenada en mi fichero de texto?

Answer (score 0):

En un perfil de Firefox se almacenan todos los datos importantes para el usuario, como marcadores, historial, cookies y contraseñas.

Restablecer Firefox

```
- Si te aparece esta página en Firefox, haz clic en este botón *Actualiza Firefox* directamente.

- No funcionará si estás utilizando otro navegador o un dispositivo móvil.
```

> Otra opción es....
>    Buscar el botón de Actualizar Firefox, en la parte superior de la página about:support de Firefox, en la sección Información para solucionar problemas. 
>       En la ventana de confirmación que se abre, haz clic en Reiniciar Firefox.
>       Firefox se cerrará y se reiniciará automáticamente. Cuando haya acabado, te aparecerá una ventana con una lista de toda la información que se ha importado. Para que Firefox vuelva a iniciarse, haz clic en Finalizar.

Los complementos que se suelen almacenar en la carpeta de perfil de Firefox, como las extensiones y los temas, se eliminarán. Los complementos almacenados en otras ubicaciones no se eliminarán, pero cualquier configuración modificada sí se restablecerán.

> Firefox conservará:

```
- Marcadores
- Historial de navegación y de descargas
- Contraseñas
- Ventanas, pestañas y grupos de pestañas abiertos
- Cookies
- Información de autocompletado de los formularios web
- Diccionario personal
```

Posdata:
El botón Reiniciar Firefox también se encuentra en la ventana del Modo seguro, en caso de que no puedas iniciar Firefox de forma normal. También puedes hacerlo de forma manual creando un nuevo perfil y transfiriendo tus datos importantes al nuevo perfil.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres un resultado "mas efectivo", te recomiendo realizar un análisis forense con Dumpzilla.
Esta herramienta te permite obtener el historial, descargas, formularios, contraseñas, marcadores, etc.
Aquí te dejo un pequeño tutorial de como se debe realizar paso a paso.

http://www.elladodelmal.com/2018/06/dumpzilla-como-hacer-un-analisis.html